# How to build login system so that only last user logged in can save?

Tags: php, file, authentication

I am working on a simple project where I have a login system with multiple users where each user will login and save form entries in a file. Idea is last user who is logged in should always have the write access (and all others write access should be revoked) and if last user logs out then second last user should have the access but if only one user is logged in then he should get the write access automatically.

- I have `login.php` page where I provide my user and password.
- If login is successful then it redirects me to `index.php` page where I have form with two textbox and a button.
- On `index.php` page I have `Save Data` button which if I click it calls `save.php` then it save form entries by overwriting in file but there is a catch here as explained below.
- I also have `logout` link on my `index.php` page which if I click then it will log me out and redirect to `login.php` page. On each logout it clear the session and clears entries from the file as well.

Here is the flow with multiple users trying to save in a file. Only the last user who is logged in will be able to save form entries in a file. All other users who logged in before should get message saying `Your write access is revoked since another user is logged in now`. For example:

- If `userA` is logged in then he should be able to save form entires in a file.
- If `userB` is logged in then `userA` write access is revoked but `userB` should be able to save.
- Now If `userC` is logged in then `userB` and `userA` write access is revoked but `userC` should be able to save.
- Similarly for other users. Idea is only last user who is logged in should be able to save and all others (who are logged in) write access should be revoked.

Now if last user logs out then second last user who was logged in should get his write access back. And similarly for others as well. Logout/Login can happen in any way from any users.

Here is my `index.php` file:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

// Start session.
session_start();

// Include helper functions.
require_once 'helpers.php';

// 2 mins in seconds
$inactive = 120; 

if(isset($_SESSION['timeout']) ) {
    $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
    if($session_life > $inactive)
    { 
        redirect('logout.php');
        return;
    }
}

$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();

// Redirect user to login page if not authenticated.
if (! check_auth()) {
    redirect('logout.php');
    return;
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Website Title</h1> <a href="logout.php">Logout</a> </div>
    <div>
        <p>Welcome back, <?= $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>!</p>
    </div>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="field1" />
        <input type="text" name="field2" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data"> </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        "use strict";
        $('form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post({
                url: 'save.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
            }).done(response => {
                response = JSON.parse(response);
                if (response.message) {
                    alert(response.message);
                }
            }).fail(jqXhr => {
                if (jqXhr.status == 400) {
                    //redirect to specified url in the response text
                    window.location.href = jqXhr.responseText; 
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my `save.php` file:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
// Start session.
session_start();
// Include helper functions.
require_once 'helpers.php';

// 2 mins in seconds
$inactive = 120; 

if(isset($_SESSION['timeout']) ) {
    $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
    if($session_life > $inactive)
    { 
        redirect('logout.php');
        return;
    }
}

$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();

// Redirect user to login page if not authenticated.
if (! check_auth()) {
    redirect('logout.php');
    return;
}

if (! is_authorized_to_write()) {
    echo json_encode([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'Your write access is revoked since another user is logged in now.',
    ]);
    return;
}

// save form entries in a file here
```

**Problem Statement**

All my above code works fine but there is a bug with multiple users trying to save form entries in a file -

- If `userA` logs in then he is able to save form entries in a file successfully.
- But if `userB` logs in then `userA` write access is revoked and `userB` can save which is fine.
- Now if `userC` logs in then `userA` and `userB` both write access is revoked and `userC` can save which is fine.

Now as you can see all three users are logged in but if `userB` logs out then `userC` has write access because he was the last one to login so it works fine. But as soon as `userC` logs out and no one is remaining then `userA` write access should be back but somehow whenever `userA` tries to save, it says someone is logged in so he cannot save. And that is the bug. I think problem is the way I am storing entries in `current_user.txt` file but somehow not able to figure out on how to store in such a way so that last user who is logged in should always have the write access and if last user logs out then second last user should have the access but if only one user is logged in then he should get the write access automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you just let them each save to their own file or use a database? In case you really desire such absurd behavior, just make the login of one user set a flag in the user table, that will restrict other's from writing the file. File-based sessions cannot be used for such functionality, because it has to be state-less.

Comment: I agree, it looks like some corpo nightmare tool.

Comment: I agree we could have done that but it's some system we have where we need to overwrite the file from each user and make changes accordingly. And this file will be used by some other process. This is just for internal system and we have like 10 users max who work on this system. So for now I need to figure out on how to do this only for those 10 users unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe it's better to "lock" the file per user request, not per login queue? Like, a user A clicks to edit it and then you store a link between the file and the user A in the database? And when user logs out, all his links (locks) are being removed?

Comment: I think problem is not about locking the file. Problem is how I am storing `last user logged in` and `last user revoked` in a `current_user.txt` file. That ordering is wrong and thats why it doesn't work. Because I use that file to figure out who is logged in and who is not logged in and basis on that I decide whose write access is revoked or not.

Comment: Not sure if PHP is really the right tool for something alike this... compared to Google Docs, where one can edit simultaneously and can see when where others are editing. If it has to be PHP, it might be worth a consideration to create a Git branch per edit, which can be merged later - so at least each of them have their revision kept - and not discarded (along with the time they spent editing it). There at least should be some visual feedback, when others are editing or done editing.

Comment: yeah I think you are right we could have used some other tools for this but somehow this is what my small team is following and I am trying to help them out with this whole silly system.

Comment: I'd already challenge the concept of editing the file directly (especially without an exclusive lock); it's a whole lot more common to edit a database and then render some file based upon the records (assuming this is record-based). With pure PHP it might also be difficult to notify other users, that they lost their edits - or might have to wait for someone else, who is currently editing; you'd need something alike Pusher, in order to push such events to the client-side. In case you plan to implement this as envisioned, they might not be amused (because nobody want to waste their time).